# Python Upload Script Won't Run in Bash File

Tags: python, bash

I have a simple script for uploading files to a server via FTP. When I include the script in the bash file it will not run, however it runs and processes fine in the terminal. Other python scripts in the same directory run without issue. Thanks in advance.

Script

```
import ftplib

session = ftplib.FTP('server address','username','password')
file = open('index.html','rb') # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR ' + '/', file) # send the file

file.close() # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

Bash File

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python3.6 "upload.py"; #path is correct

exit 0
```

Comment: As written, `upload.py` has to be in the current working directory of the process that starts your `bash` script, which is not necessarily the directory which *contains* the `bash` script.

Comment: Well the script is started by me clicking it manually or will be run by CRON. Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Anyone else have a suggestion?

Comment: Is there a good reason you can't use the full path to `upload.py`?

Answer (score 1):

In Bash File give the complete path to the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $PWD > /tmp/test.txt
python3.6 "/absolute/path/to/upload.py"; #path is correct

exit 0
```

---

check the directory in which the program run.

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt
```

---